# Rails 3.2 delayed job a pdf email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a page where the user can select multiple `costprojects` to create a single pdf (including S3 attachments).  It works fine - except if the user selects quite a few, then app will time out (30 sec).

So, I would like to create the pdf and email it in the background using `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`.

This works without delayed job:

```
 def pdfemail
    @costprojects = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_ids])
    pdf = CombinePDF.new
    @costprojects.each do |costproject|
      @costproject = costproject
      pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "SLCO Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
      pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf2)
      costproject.attachments.each do |attachment|
        pdf << CombinePDF.parse( Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( attachment.attach.url ) ) )
      end
    end
    useremail = current_user.email
    CostpdfMailer.costpdf_email(useremail,pdf).deliver
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = 'An Email containing a PDF has been sent to you!'
  end
```

This was my first try that didn't work - I added:

```
handle_asynchronously :pdfemail
```

My second try:

```
 def pdfemail
    @costprojects = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_ids])
    CostprojectsController.delay.pdfemail2(@costprojects)
  end

  def self.pdfemail2(costprojects)
    @costprojects = costprojects
    pdf = CombinePDF.new
    @costprojects.each do |costproject|
      @costproject = costproject
      pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "SLCO Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
      pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf2)
      costproject.attachments.each do |attachment|
        pdf << CombinePDF.parse( Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( attachment.attach.url ) ) )
      end
    end
    useremail = current_user.email
    CostpdfMailer.costpdf_email(useremail,pdf).deliver
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = 'An Email containing a PDF has been sent to you!'
  end
```

With the 2nd try, I get:

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for CostprojectsController:Class
```

The same `render_to_string` worked when it was just `pdfemail`.

3rd try:

```
pdf2 = CostprojectsController.new.render_to_string pdf: "SLCO Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
```

With the 3rd try, `@costproject` isn't getting passed to costprojects/viewproject.pdf.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't handle a controller action asynchronously.

And you can't call controller methods like `render`, `render_to_string` and `flash[:notice]` from within a class method `self.pdfemail` since those methods are instance methods on the controller.

You'll have to separate out the pdf email logic from the controller response logic, like this:

```
def pdfemail      
  pdf_template = render_to_string pdf: "SLCO Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"

  PdfMailer.new.pdf_email params[:costproject_ids], current_user.email, pdf_template

  redirect_to :back
  flash[:notice] = 'An Email containing a PDF has been sent to you!'
end
```

Then in another file:

```
class PdfMailer
  def pdf_email(costproject_ids, useremail, pdf_template)
    @costprojects = Costproject.find(costproject_ids)
    pdf = CombinePDF.new

    @costprojects.each do |costproject|
      @costproject = costproject
      # This part needs work, you can't use render_to_string here.
      # You'll have to generate this pdf some other way.
      pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "SLCO Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
      pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf2)

      costproject.attachments.each do |attachment|
        pdf_response = Net::HTTP.get URI.parse(attachment.attach.url)
        pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf_response)
      end
    end

    CostpdfMailer.costpdf_email(useremail, pdf).deliver
  end
  handle_asynchronously :pdf_email
end
```

The `PdfMailer` class does not use any controller instance methods such as `render`, `render_to_string`, or `flash`, that has to be taken care of in the controller since you *can't handle controller action asynchronously*. Consequently you have to pass in the data you need, in this case the `costproject_ids`, `useremail` from `current_user.email`.

Inside the `PdfMailer` class you'll have to generate the pdf in that loop with some other method than the controller's `render_to_string`. There's plenty of other tools for this here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation.

On your 3rd try: it isn't working because you're instantiating a new controller which doesn't have the @costproject instance variable set in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!  `class PdfMailer` in another file - where should I put this new file? Helpers?

Comment: You could put it in lib, or app/services. helpers are only for modules that get included into controllers.

Comment: Would it make sense to put it in `mailers` and change to `class PdfMailer < ActionMailer::Base`?

Comment: If the pdf generation code doesn't get too complex then maybe. But generally you want your classes to do one thing only.